# Why does glass etching cream contain sulfuric acid?

Tags: equipment

The [MSDS](https://www.glassetchingsecrets.com/wp-content/uploads/Armour-etch-SDS-2015.pdf) for various glass etching creams all show that they're primarily composed of 4 substances (the composition percentages vary):

- Ammonium Bifluoride  - 20 - 40%
- Sodium Bifluoride    - 5 - 10%
- Sulphuric Acid       - 1 - 5%
- Barium Sulfate       - 1 - 5%

The purpose of the fluoride ingredients is obvious. They decompose into hydrofluoric acid (presumably when reacting with water in the air) and do the actual etching. But why is there Sulphuric Acid? It doesn't react with glass at all.

My speculation would be that perhaps it's a strong desiccant and it serves to slow the reaction?

Comment: $\ce{HF2- + H+ <=> 2 HF}$, resp.   $\ce{F- + H+ <=>  HF}$

Comment: Using bifluorides with a mineral acid is technically the second best after using directly HF(aq), as nobody wants to manipulate with stock HF(aq) unless absolutely necessary. (One bigger splash can kill you after few hours or days, unless treated. It is extremely painful and may left permanent damage.)

Answer (score 0):

Both Ammonium bifluoride (NH4HF2) and sodium bifluoride (NaHF2) when reacted with water, produce the primary etchant for glass which turns out to be Hydrofluoric acid (HF). The reaction goes as followed:

NH4HF2 (or) NaHF2 + H2O → HF + NH4OH (or) NaOH

NOw that we got our etching agent Hydrofluoric acid (HF) which is very strong acid capable of etching glass as it reacts with the silicon dioxide (SiO2) present in the glass structure, producing soluble Fluorosilicic acid (H2SiF6) and water:

SiO2 (glass) + 6HF → H2SiF6 + 2H2O

Then coming to your actual question, why is there Sulphuric Acid? there are a couple of reasons like:

1. It helps in lowering the ph of the solution creating an acidic environment to aid the actual process. This contribution promotes the dissociation of fluorides and thereby supporting the reaction between HF and glass indirectly.
2. It contributes to overall consistency and stability of the etching cream. Increasing and decreasing the acidity of the cream, sulfuric acid can help to optimize the viscosity, adhesion, and other physical properties of the cream, ensuring uniform application and etching results.
3. It may be used in the process of production to
   purification of raw materials, to increase the span before expiry.

Comment: Oddly, Claude and ChatGPT had very similar answers, also giving me three points (about kinetics, viscosity, and moisture control).